# Why is SQLite3 Querying slower than building a new directory index with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a script that needs all files in a given directory to be indexed for easier querying(ex: find the file with a given filename that has the most recent modified date). I have been walking through the entire directory and adding each file to a dataframe every time the script runs. I would think that instead of gathering this data for every file, It would be quicker to query a database and only update if the files modified data changed but in testing, this was way slower. Why is this? Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Result:

```
Index with pandas took 0:06:53.352515
Innitial index with SQLite3 took 0:43:20.042651
second index with SQLite3 took 0:21:48.863566
```

```
"""
{Description}
The purpose of this exercise is to index a directory for later use.
We will try two methods to quantify the benefits of updating a SQLite db
    rather than re-indexing into a pandas dataframe each time.
"""

# Built-in/Generic Imports
import os
import sys
# […]

# Libs
import pandas as pd # Or any other
import datetime
import sqlite3

def main():
    dbPath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'testing.db')
    indexPath = Random_Directory_with_tons_of_files
    setupSQL(dbPath)
    print('Index with pandas took ' + str(testPandas(indexPath)))
    print('Innitial index with SQLite3 took ' + str(testSQLite(indexPath, dbPath)))
    print('second index with SQLite3 took ' + str(testSQLite(indexPath, dbPath)))

def setupSQL(dbPath):
    if os.path.exists(dbPath):
        os.remove(dbPath)
    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbPath)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE testTable
             (fullPath, fileName, modifiedDate)''')
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def testPandas(path):
    startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    testIndex = pd.DataFrame(columns=['fullPath', 'fileName', 'modifiedDate'])
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            testIndex = testIndex.append({'fullPath' : os.path.join(dirpath, filename),
                                          'fileName' : filename,
                                          'modifiedDate' : os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))}, ignore_index=True)
    return datetime.datetime.now() - startTime

def testSQLite(path, dbPath):
    startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbPath)
    c = conn.cursor()
    
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            c.execute('SELECT * FROM testTable WHERE fullPath=?', [(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))])
            row = c.fetchone()
            if row == None:
                #File is not in database, add it
                c.execute('INSERT INTO testTable VALUES (?,?,?)', [
                              (os.path.join(dirpath, filename)),
                              (filename),
                              (os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)))
                              ])
                conn.commit()
            elif row[2] != os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)):
                #Modified Date has changed, update it.
                c.execute('UPDATE testTable SET modifiedDate=? WHERE fullPath=?', [(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))),(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))])
                conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    return datetime.datetime.now() - startTime

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Starting')
    main()
    print('Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference between sqlite and pandas is that sqlite is a **file** based database. When sqlite connects to a database it only loads certain parts of the file that holds the actual data. Once you query it for something it goes back and reads the file until it finds what it needs then returns that to you. Here is a stack overflow question asking about sqlite and how it loads data.

[Sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156832/does-sqlite-load-whole-db-file-into-memory-when-connected#:%7E:text=2%20Answers&text=No%2C%20Sqlite%20will%20read%20data%20for%20hard%20disk%20by%20paging.&text=There%20is%20an%20option%20when,memory%20database%20will%20be%20empty.)

One thing you could try to see how fast it would speed up is to have sqlite create an inmemory database. Instead of passing in a path to a file for sqlite just pass in `:MEMORY:` and that should create a in memory sqlite databse. Then retry your benchmark and see if it improves in speed. **WARNING** depending on how many files you're grabbing you may use a lot of memory for this.

`conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')`

Comment: I instead indexed the directory into a SQLite3 db held in memory as you suggested and the time went down to 0:05:43 which is an improvement. I am unsure how to load a db into memory however. How would I take this database built in memory and save it to a file. Next, how would I recall that file into memory for the next time I want to run this script? the purpose here would be to determine the time savings from having the db already built and simply needing to update where necessary.

Comment: I must of miss read your question earlier. So if you need the database to persist to the hard drive then don't use `:memory:`. Instead save to a file and change how you query the db. First walk your directories like normal but instead of adding it to the db add it to a list containing the tuple of data you retrieved. Once you've walked you directory use the `executemany` function rather than `execute` when you insert into db. Secondly dont do a select then based on what it return to update or insert. Use `upsert` which is part of sqlite. https://sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html

Comment: By using `executemany` and upsert you are no longer querying the db twice for every file you find. You now query only once using a massive upsert statement. There is one caveat and that is sqlite has a limit on how many items can be inserted in one upsert query which i think is 500. So if you have 5000 files you will run `executemany` 10 times with chunks of 500 from your dataset.

Comment: Yes but, if i must walk my entire directory and build dataframe with the information for each file, then i will not be saving time by having a database(time it takes to write a line to a dataframe is less than the time it takes to check if my database has that filein it already.) that was the purpose of this test. i think my best path forward is to avoid needing a directory index in the first place. thank you for the help, the :memory: trick helped alot and might actually be better than pandas when i later query it in my code.

Comment: It's hard to get the best of both worlds. If you need it to be saved for use later this is kinda the only option. But when i said to save it to a list of tuples I don't mean to use pandas. Just use a basic list and tuple that python offers. This will be faster than adding them to pandas since it wont do any preprocessing of the data. Hope this helps and good luck with your project.